# Core Data Error: Execute Fetch Request Error - Crashes when trying to access Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos

I'm using Core Data for my iOS project and I am getting an "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'" error when running the app. I do have an entity for my app, but am not sure why this error persists.

Here is the Core Data Code in the file that is having the error:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ClassesCell";

    ClassTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ClassTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(ClassTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Classes *classID = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.classLabel.text = classID.classTitle;
    cell.periodLabel.text = classID.period;
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyClassesID" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    assert(self.managedObjectContext);

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"period" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
   [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;


}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Has the `managedObjectContext` been set or is it `nil` when the code is run?

Comment: @Wain I am not exactly sure. This is my first time coding on iOS. Where would I be able to find that out?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where you create the fetch request and debug to check that the reference is set.

Comment: @Wain I did as you suggested and it turns out the the managedObjectContext is nil

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the managed object context reference is set. If it isn't set then the fetch request will not be able to locate the entity.

---

You must have a class somewhere which is the owner of the managed object context. By default (from the Apple supplied templates) this is the app delegate. When the app delegate creates the controller class it should pass the controller a reference to the MOC. If the app delegate doesn't create the controller then the controller can go to the app delegate to get a reference.

Comment: How do I set the reference?

Comment: I have the same Exception generated for the fetch request and I have checked that my MOC is not nil. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST:** 
It is good practice to refrain from using any NSObject reserve words like "Class" when you create your Data Model. I just tried in Xcode 4.6.3 using the name "class" as an attribute and Data Modeller told me "class" was a reserved name in NSObject. The same goes for words like self, entity, description or others.

**SECOND:**
Also, what may have happened is that you initially created your data model, ran your Core Data app to test it and then you modified your Core Data Model and now you are trying to run the application again against an old sqlite database.  To fix this, you can delete the SQLite database in the directory your simulator uses and then run your app again. NOTE: Do this only when you are doing initial development and never after you have released an app. After release of your app use Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration.

**INSTRUCTIONS:**

**Start a terminal console**.

To find where it is first get to the iPhone simulator directory like so:

**cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/**

Then depending on which iOS version you are testing (mine was 6.1) change the line below that suits yours:

**cd 6.1/Applications**

The directory names the simulator creates is cryptic looking. Yours will likely be the last one or if you are going back and fourth between simulating different projects, it might be the second last, third last etc. First try the last one. Mine was the following: F53A66CD-DB9A-4440-9178-28BCF4A7A571
Therefore I did the following:

**cd F53A66CD-DB9A-4440-9178-28BCF4A7A571**

Then enter:

**cd Documents**

Then enter the following command to list the files:

**ls**

You should see your .sqlite file listed. **Say yours was myClasses.sqlite**

To delete it type the following:

**rm myClasses.sqlite**

Then build and run to test your application again.

Dougpan.com

Comment: I tried that and the file was called HomeworkApp.sqlite and I removed it. After running the app again, the same error persisted

Comment: Did you try using Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration?  A hash is used to compare any modifications to the Data Model to what is in code. Also keep in mind that if, while you have an attribute selected and you chose Edit, Create NSManagedObject subclass, your code could be using a class. You may need to update that too and look through and make updates to your code where those classes are being used.

Comment: Try putting some debugging code to test your fetch request like: NSArray *fetch = [itemController.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"%d",fetch.count);